# Prove that the quotient $(U+W)/W$ is naturally isomorphic to $U/(U\cap W)$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I have that $V$ is a vector space over field $F$ and $W$ and $U$ are subspaces. How do I show that the quotient $U+W/W$ is isomorphic to $U/(U\cap W)$?

Comment: Do you mean $(U+W)/W$?

Answer (score 0):

This is a general group theory result:  If $N$ is normal in a group $G$, and $H$ is a subgroup of $G$, then $HN/N \cong H / (H\cap N)$.  To prove this , consider the map (using your notation):
\begin{eqnarray}
\phi: U &\to& (U + W)/W \\
u & \mapsto & u + W
\end{eqnarray}
The map $\phi$ is a morphism of additive groups.  It is not too hard to see that this map is surjective, since every element in $(U+W)/W$ is of the form $u + W$ for some $u\in U$.  Then you can show that the kernel of $\phi$ is equal to $U\cap W$.  The Fundamental Theorem of Homomorphisms then implies the isomorphism $U/(U\cap W) \cong (U+W)/W$.

Answer (score 0):

Prove that $[u+w] \mapsto [u]$ is an isomorphism between $(U+W)/W$ and $U/(U\cap W)$. So you have to show that the map is well defined, linear, has trivial kernel and is surjective.